# Why the validation message are not appearing with required_if?

Tags: laravel

I want that the fields payment_mb, payment_c and invoice_issuer are mandatory if the user introduces a value greater than "0" for field registration_type_price.

But its not working, the validation message is not appearing with "required_if:registration_type_price,>,0'". Do you know why?

```
$rules =  [
    ...
    'payment_mb' => 'required_without:payment_c|required_if:registration_type_price,>,0',
    'payment_c' => 'required_without:payment_mb|required_if:registration_type_price,>,0',

    'invoice_issuer' => 'required_if:registration_type_price,>,0',
];

$customMessages = [
    ...
    'payment_mb.required_if' => 'The field payment methods is mandatory.',
    'payment_c.required_if' =>  'The field payment methods is mandatory.',

    'invoice_issuer.required_if' => 'The field invoice issuer is mandatory..'

];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#personal_detail_form").validate({
     rules: {
        full_name: {
            lettersonly: true
        },phone_number : {
            number : true,
            minlength:10,
            maxlength:10
        },city : {
            lettersonly : true
        },pin_code : {
            digits : true,
            minlength:6,
            maxlength:6 
        },
```